# Property for a continuous function with the same value

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-functions

I'm doing Real Analysis and I'm at a point where I'm exploring continuous functions.

I stumbled on this question

*Let A ⊆ R and f : R → R a continuous function such that f(x) = 6 for all x ∈ A. What property must the set A have in order to conclude from this that f(x) = 6 for all x ∈ R? Be sure to give reasons for your answer.*

I tried looking for the property but couldn't find anything concrete.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.  There are constant functions....is that what you were asking?

Comment: It would be appreciated  if you edit the question to add: 1. The exact question, quoted word for word.  2. Your thoughts and efforts into the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you encountered the notion of dense sets?

Comment: Yes I have encountered dense sets before.

Comment: What happens if $A$ is dense? What can happen in $A$ is not dense?